# nginx/gunicorn log initial request on receive not after processing?

Tags: nginx, logging, request, gunicorn, access-log

Both Nginx & gunicorn log requests AFTER they have processed them.

Two questions, is the timestamp then related to when the response is finalised and sent back and if so is there a way to log initial request received time in either server log?